# Does it affect the probability of successful trasmission if a jammer hops channels?

Tags: wireless

Suppose an attacker tries to jam a wireless communication. There are 10 channels available and the legitimate sender chooses one of them of transmission randomly every 1s. If it transmits data for 5s then it will change channel 5 times. Also, assume that the attacker can jam only one channel at a given time.

If the attacker is fixed, ie there is only one fixed jammed channel for all five seconds, then the probability that the sender will successfully transmit all five seconds (all 5 chunks of data will be transmitted successfully) is 0.9^5.

What will this probability be if the attacker also hops every 1s?

There are two approaches I have encountered. One is to say that no matter what the attacker does, the "experiment" for the sender is the same; it is that of randomly choosing a channel out of 10 five times. So the probability is the same as before.

The other is that there two sets of channels, set S={c1,c2,c3,c4,c5} and set A={c1,c2,c3,c4,c5}, the first contains the channels that the sender has chosen after 5s and the second the channels the attacker has chosen. The probability we are asking originally can now be seen as the probability that these two sets have no common elements. Which ends up being (0.9^5)^2.

Which of the two is correct? And what is wrong with the wrong one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both, the legitimate sender and the jammer, are picking their channels at synchronized intervals using independent randomness, the probability for successful transmission is indeed (9/10)<sup>5</sup>.

The logic in your second approach is not correct because for a successful transmission, it is not required that both sets of channels have no common element. It is sufficient if the channels are different at any given point in time.

Consider the following example of unaffected transmission.

```
used channel:      1 2 3 4 5
jammed channel:    8 5 9 7 7
```

Even though both sets overlap on channel 5, it is only jammed during a period where it is not used.

Note my weasel wording in the first paragraph, though. It is highly unrealistic that both parties have synchronized intervals. But if they haven't, a jammer interval can overlap two sender intervals (or even three if the period is not exactly 1 second) and the probability becomes more complicated.